# MVC for a CMS? What about themes?

Tags: model-view-controller, content-management-system, design-patterns

I understand what is MVC and CMS. I understand MVC pattern and how CMS should working. But I have problem with theming and the pattern.

Example:

When CMS is installed on serwer I want to change my homepage. I want to display some additional data. I change my homepage template and add a function call to pull data from DB. My new data will be displayed on my homepage. :)

But when I do this I broke MVC pattern because in this situation View decide which data should be read from DB to display on my homepage.

So... is it MVC for a CMS? Or maybe it shouldn't be a clear MVC pattern to work with situations like this? Maybe I should forget about patterns? I'm confusing...

PS
Wordpress it's not build on MVC pattern, I guess?

Comment: Patterns don't always have to be pure. In ASP.NET MVC, for example, there are known impurities having to do with Subcontrollers and the RenderAction helper. Do what works. More specifically, do what works best for your particular application.

Comment: I'm thinking about using RenderAction for situations like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Design patterns like MVC are meant to be about separating your display code from the business logic, etc. This makes it easier to change any part without affecting any of the other parts (eg. change the templates without having to worry about accidentally changing any business logic).

You situation sounds like the function you are adding is simple view logic? It might be best to put the function into a `Helper` and have the helper call for the data through a `Model`. Then, in your view, just call the Helper.

In pseudocode:

**Helper**

```
function get_whatever_data () {
    // get the actual data from the model
    return SomeModel.get_the_data_thats_needed_here()
}
```

**View**

```
<div id="some-id">
    <? print get_whatever_data() ?>
</div>
```